# Is possible to fetch associative array grouped by the values of a specific column in a simple way with PDO?

Tags: php

I have this simple dataset:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Users   | Location  | 
+---------+-----------+
| User1   | Location1 |
| User2   | Location2 |
| User3   | Location2 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I need to put this record in an array like this:

```
Array 
    (
      [Location1] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => User1
                     )
      [Location2] => Array
                     (
                       [0] => User2
                       [1] => User3
                     )
    )
```

Using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)` I obtain this array:

```
Array 
(
  Location_1 => Array 
                (
                  [0] => Array 
                         (
                           User_1 => Username
                           [0] => Username
                         )
                )
 Location_2 => Array 
                (
                  [0] => Array 
                         (
                           User_2 => Username
                           [0] => Username
                         )
                  [1] => Array 
                         (
                           User_3 => Username
                           [0] => Username
                         )
                )
)
```

I think the best practice could be to reduce the array but I need some help. 
I even tryied `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)` that return an array like this:

```
Array
(
  Location1 => User1
  Location2 => User2
)
```

In this case, it would possible obtain this one?

```
Array
(
  Location1 => User1
  Location2 => User2, User3
)
```

Comment: You cannot get what you want automatically from a fetch call. You will have to write some PHP to process the resultset into what you want

Comment: [Check Example 3 in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Isn't that the result you want? They're combining `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you!